# Python - click on sharepoint CSS menu to download to excel with selenium .ms-core-menu-title

Tags: python, css, selenium, sharepoint

I'm trying to automate the following process

1. Accesing a Sharepoint site
2. Loading some input data
3. Running a query that retrieves some data
4. Download it to excel through a menue (Actions, Download, Excel)

I was successful with steps 1 to 3 and made it work perfectly but I'm stuck with the forth one.

I recorded the 3 clicks in the menu needed to download to excel getting the following ids:

```
css=#m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_ctl01_t > .ms-core-menu-arrow
css=#m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_Export > .ms-core-menu-title
css=#mp1_1_3_Anchor > #m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_EXCELOPENXML
```

Then, I created the following code:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ms-core-menu-arrow").click() # click on Actions menu
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ms-core-menu-title').click() # click Excel
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#mp1_1_3_Anchor > #m_sqlRsWebPart_RSWebPartToolbar_ctl00_RptControls_RSActionMenu_EXCELOPENXML').click() # click Excel
```

When I run it, it clicks on Action menu (first step), but then it gets stuck with the following message:
"Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ms-core-menu-title"}

I don't understand why the code is able to click on the first button ".ms-core-menu-Arrow" but not on the second one ".ms-core-menu-title"

I tried to skip the second row of code and go directly to the third one for downloading to excel but it fails the same way in identifying the css element.

Any help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Could it be that program is going too quickly, and the last menu option hasn't loaded yet?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand how it works (I'm new on it), but I tried again to record the sequence with Selenium in Chrome and instead of returning CSS button codes, it returned "ids"

I finally targeted it with the following code and it worked!!!

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ms-core-menu-arrow").click() # click on Actions menue
time.sleep(6)
driver.find_element_by_id('mp1_0_2_Anchor').click() # click Download
driver.find_element_by_id('mp1_1_3_Anchor').click() # click Excel
```

I have to add 6 seconds after the first menue to load so the following buttons could be pressed so anyways your answer helped me to figure it out!

Many thanks!!